# Be nice with the comments

Tags: discussion

Just a reminder to please be nice with the comments. It seems to me (in a completely statistically unsound survey based on my own impressions) that we're getting a bit snarky with the comments at the the moment.

I certainly concede that we seem to be getting some spectacularly stupid questions recently, but responding to them with snide or snarky comments isn't the best way to deal with them. If you don't want to take the time to politely explain to the OP how their question could be improved then please just downvote, vote to close or vote to delete as your reputation allows, then go and calm down with a nice cup of coffee.

Comment: This. I've also been known to take my snarky comments to chat if I feel that have literary merit.

Comment: Care to provide any examples?

Comment: It's the damn chat room gang at root; I'm sure of it  :<)

Comment: Related:  It's been interesting to me to watch the evolution of this community (and myself) in the 3 years or so that I've been here.  Wikipedians have a notion of a [Wikibreak](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wikipedia:Wikibreak) that, perhaps, might be applicable here.

Comment: Heck, thinking out loud, what if the regular contributors (answering/voting/commenting/chatting/snarking etc.) here just took a break en masse for a week or so.  That might be interesting.

Comment: @John Rennie : I share your sentiment, but can we have some examples please?

Comment: @JohnDuffield ... it might be tough to show examples without things getting meta-snarky...

Comment: I don't disagree with the OP but note that this site is an oasis of calm and civility compared to so many places.

Comment: @Gert: I agree absolutely. The Physics Stack exchange is an extraordinary resource. I just wish it had existed in the 1970s when I was a teenage physics nerd, err, "enthusiast" :-).

Comment: Wholeheartedly agree with the sentiments expressed. I cringe at the (borderline) hostile comments I sometimes see - but they are a minority, and I don't know if there is an uptrend. Perhaps a new flag ("bit snarky") on comments would allow us to do a formal count... such a flag would require no action from the mods but give us a chance to measure the sentiment of the community (with a high rep threshold to enable).

Comment: Postulate- Misuse of tag Homework-and-exercises is responsible for a multitude of shopping questions, leading to possible frustration to a potential reviewer in turn leading to a comment with probable dense language with a good intention.

Comment: @Sathyam: Shopping questions? What do you mean?

Comment: Asking 'you' to shop for 'me' or asking recommendation about a commodity to the 'expert' without caring to research for himself or just plainly 'Which is better, cow milk or goat milk? please decide and buy it for me.'

Comment: @Floris I think that'd probably be quite annoying to deal with for the moderators.

Comment: @Danu the point was this would not be a flag that needs dealing with - it would be a "sentiment gauge" not a "actionable flag".

Comment: @Floris It'd still require them to look at it: A "snarky" comment might overstep the (ill-defined) boundary.

Comment: @Danu I would propose that you mark it "offensive or rude" if you wanted it looked at, and "borderline snarky"if you didn't think it needed a moderator. A bit of a change to the model I agree - may not be worth it.

Comment: @Floris I think that custom flag reasons is not something that is easily implemented. I also think this is a non-issue, so I guess that influenced my view too (I guess I'm probably one of the perpetrators ;-).

Comment: It's a fine line.  I agree that comments like "you're an ignorant slut. How did you ever learn to log in" are unacceptable, but a lot of new posters get really upset when told that they need to learn more basic {some field of physics or math} before attempting to understand the question they're asking.  What to do with them?

Comment: @CarlWitthoft: if a question or answer is crap you have to tell the OP it's crap. To do otherwise is not fair on the OP or anyone who might read the crap answer in the future. It's just that, well, I'd probably avoid using the word *crap* :-)

Comment: Ahh, well, comments on answers can be more harsh than comments on the question, then?  ;/}

Comment: @AlfredCentauri: "Heck, thinking out loud, what if the regular contributors (answering/voting/commenting/chatting/snarking etc.) here just took a break en masse for a week or so. That might be interesting." If by "interesting" you mean "total disaster" then I'm with you :-) Can you imagine what would happen if the close queue were ignored for a week? We'd turn into a homework service.

Comment: I'm relatively new here but I have often found the first comments on a new question to reflect criticism rather than aid  to the questioner.  There was one in particular the other day (I forget the question) where the first comment said something like, "Please use capital letters to start sentences.  There is an expectation of professionalism on this site..."  I am indeed bothered by questions full of typos and poor use of language, but I don't think that should be the first thing commenters choose to address.  I'd hope they'd go after what doesn't make sense.

Comment: Newbie too. If a question is "crap" (which is a the truth of it) should we not help the inquirer identify the right question, the mainstream aspects of the question or improve it. Assuming there is some interest in growing the user base?
What is it they are really trying to find out, do we know it ourselves, and can we share it?
Perhaps we need to post a big thank-yuo for your question first before even reviewing it.  We could say something like how we appreciate the inquirey and curiosity, and that responses may include technical criticism of the question do not diminish that.