# I can not log in "meta.physics.stackexchange". Why?

Tags: discussion

For example, I want to write an answer to the topic:

[Be nice with the comments](https://physics.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/7243/be-nice-with-the-comments)

that has the address:

"meta.physics.stackexchange.com/questions/7243/be-nice-with-the-comments"

If I press "log in" the effect is zero. Why?

I am redirected to the same link:
[image]
without any warning like "you are not allowed to log in" or other explanation.

Comment: Have you tried clicking on your user profile on this site, and then clicking on "meta user" up near the top?

Comment: I have flagged it to be migrated to meta.physics.SE since these questions should definitely not be here. However, another place this could be asked is meta.SE as well for discussing software problems with stackexchange.

Comment: man, the guy says he can't log to MPSE and you want to move his question there ?

Comment: If you use the HTTPS Everywhere extension from EFF, there's a known bug in how the site interacts with that extension. For a solution, try disabling HTTPS Everywhere (if you use it) and accessing the main site via plain old HTTP, then log out of your account, then visit meta and try to log in there.

Comment: @Fabrice NEYRET : well spotted that man!

Comment: @fabrice: questions about the site are to be posted on Meta, not the main. In any event, op would be able to *see* it there even without logging in.

Comment: @KyleKanos OP would be able to see it but would not be  (is not) able to respond to comments or edit their post.  This can be discussed in chat, though.